# Adding Properties to JSON Object

Tags: json

I am using jQuery Autocomplete, and when I select a record from the autocomplete results, it returns this as JSON:

```
{
    "label": "123 Fakeville St",
    "Address": "123 Fakeville St",
    "YOC": 1994,
    "value": "123 Fakeville St"
}
```

Is there a way I can reformat it so it looks like this?

```
{
    "house": {
        "properties": {
            "label": "123 Fakeville St",
            "Address": "123 Fakeville St",
            "YOC": 1994,
            "value": "123 Fakeville St"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put put the old JSON into a new JSON object under the property `house`:

```
var oldObj = JSON.parse(oldJson);
var newObj = {
    house: {
        properties: oldObj
    }
};
var newJson = JSON.stringify(newObj);
```

Or, in a single line, the value should be:

```
JSON.stringify({house:{properties:JSON.parse(oldJson)}})
```

```js
var oldJson = '{"label":"123 Fakeville St","Address":"123 Fakeville St","YOC":1994,"value":"123 Fakeville St"}';

console.log(JSON.stringify({house:{properties:JSON.parse(oldJson)}}));
```

Comment: Thank you! I also need the label, Address, YOC as part of "properties". Does this mean I have to do what you have suggested twice? Once for "house", and then for "properties"? Nest it twice...?

Comment: @mapr Oops, I misread the JSON you wanted. No, you don't have to do it twice. Give me a sec, I'll update my post...

Comment: Much simpler than what I was suggesting. Yes this works!

Comment: @mapr I'm glad I helped! (feel free to accept to show the community it helped you =P)